# Ubuntu перехватывает контекст VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Запускаю игру "warcraft 3" внутри VirtualBox в режиме "Full screen". Не смотря на это, при нажатии комбинации клавиш Left-Alt + правая кнопка мыши во время игры, всплывает pop-up окно Ubuntu с пунктами меню ("Maximize", "Minimize", и прочие). Также, при достижении указателем мыши границы экрана, мышь как бы залипает в этой позиции время от времени, что затрудняет процесс игры.

Как сделать так, чтобы контекст Ubuntu не был внутри VirtualBox?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В настройки машины заглянуть?

Comment: @PinkTux спасибо за отклик. Тщательно просмотрел все настройки машины. К сожалению, не нашел ничего, что могло бы поспособствовать решению моей проблемы. Решил задать вопрос здесь

Comment: Для начала - проверить стоят ли Guest Additions. Потом попробовать попереключать в меню Input->Mouse Integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PinkTux дал верный ответ в комментариях. Произвел установку Guest Additions, и включил режим "Mouse Integration". Затем по нажатию на окно виртуалбокса, в модальном окне, нажал "Capture", и курсор мышки перестал выходить за пределы экрана